# How to force the Y axis to only use integers

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

I'm plotting a histogram using the matplotlib.pyplot module and I am wondering how I can force the y-axis labels to only show integers (e.g. 0, 1, 2, 3 etc.) and not decimals (e.g. 0., 0.5, 1., 1.5, 2. etc.).

I'm looking at the guidance notes and suspect the answer lies somewhere around [matplotlib.pyplot.ylim](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.ylim) but so far I can only find stuff that sets the minimum and maximum y-axis values.

```
def doMakeChart(item, x):
    if len(x)==1:
        return
    filename = "C:\Users\me\maxbyte3\charts\\"
    bins=logspace(0.1, 10, 100)
    plt.hist(x, bins=bins, facecolor='green', alpha=0.75)
    plt.gca().set_xscale("log")
    plt.xlabel('Size (Bytes)')
    plt.ylabel('Count')
    plt.suptitle(r'Normal Distribution for Set of Files')
    plt.title('Reference PUID: %s' % item)
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.savefig(filename + item + '.png')
    plt.clf()
```

Comment: This question isn't a duplicate of [Python matplotlib restrict to integer tick locations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11258212/7758804), because the other is `import pylab`, not `import matplotlib`

Answer (score 67, accepted):

If you have the y-data

```
y = [0., 0.5, 1., 1.5, 2., 2.5]
```

You can use the maximum and minimum values of this data to create a list of natural numbers in this range. For example,

```
import math
print range(math.floor(min(y)), math.ceil(max(y))+1)
```

yields

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

You can then set the y tick mark locations (and labels) using [matplotlib.pyplot.yticks](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.yticks):

```
yint = range(min(y), math.ceil(max(y))+1)

matplotlib.pyplot.yticks(yint)
```

Comment: Oh, cool! Thanks you, that's pushing me in the right direction! I'm generating a whole bunch of charts, this means the y values are generated on the fly for each one. Is there a way of getting the limits graph being built and replace the default lables with these new ones?

Comment: Of course you can: from the `matplotlib.pyplot.yticks` documentation (did you read this) the first code snippet is `locs, labels = yticks()`.

Comment: Hmm, I did read it indeed. But I find documentation utterly impenetrable most of the time. I really struggle to translate the docs into meaningful code. `get_view_interval()` is Ī guess the method to reach the limits, but I have no idea from the docs how you link that call to the y axis in graph in question. `yLimits = matplotlib.pyplot.yticks(get_view_interval())`?

Comment: I agree the matplotlib documentation could be better. The code in my last comment is *all* that you need. Assuming you have used `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` then `locs, labels = plt.yticks()` will return the current y-values of the axis labels in `locs` and the labels associated with those values in `labels`. Note, `plt.yticks` gets the labels for the current plot. If you have a handle to a plot you can (I think) use `handle.yticks`.

Comment: OK. Thank you. I really do appreciate your help and time, and you have given me plenty to work from.

Comment: Great, I tried this, using this range [0, 1, 2, 3], I don't get an even amount of room between the 0 and the 1 y-range, 1-2 is huge, how do you fix that?

Comment: In Python 3.x range is an iterator so "range()" becomes "list(range())". See, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18265935/python-create-list-with-numbers-between-2-values

Comment: you should write in your answer that this works: ```from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator

ax = plt.figure().gca()
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))```

Comment: @CharlieParker - that's already another answer, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38096332/623518.

Answer (score 265):

Here is another way:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator

ax = plt.figure().gca()
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))
```

Comment: Is there a way of using integers only in both the yaxis and xaxis?

Comment: This is the right way to go !

Comment: Importantly, if your plot displays values with range < 1 (say from 0.2 to 0.5) it does keep the float values silently and will not modify your plot.

Comment: why can't we just plt object, why we have to handle 10 different variable, ax, plt, gca etc.

Comment: @fedvasu matplotlib  provides two interfaces for plotting: MATLAB style plotting using pyplot, and Object Oriented Interface.  See https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/lifecycle.html or https://medium.com/@kapil.mathur1987/matplotlib-an-introduction-to-its-object-oriented-interface-a318b1530aed

Comment: If using pandas to plot, you can get the axis with `ax = df.plot()`

Comment: Using `ax.yaxis.get_major_locator().set_params(integer=True)` lets you get rid of the additional import.

Comment: IMHO, this should be the accepted answer

Comment: Is there a way to force **minor** ticks to use integers only as well?

Comment: I can never get this to work, so I usually do `x = list(map(str, x))` and bingo!

Comment: If you need to set both axes: `axes = plt.figure().gca()
axes.xaxis.get_major_locator().set_params(integer=True)
axes.yaxis.get_major_locator().set_params(integer=True)`

Answer (score 14):

this works for me:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.hist(...

# make the y ticks integers, not floats
yint = []
locs, labels = plt.yticks()
for each in locs:
    yint.append(int(each))
plt.yticks(yint)
```

Comment: It's always a good idea to describe why the given code solves the problem. Please [edit] your answer to include such a description.

Comment: This is the only solution that works for me, thanks! I would just add one minor edit, because this solution omits the last tick and it's ugly. So I would add two more lines after the `for` loop: `last=yint[-1]+1` and `yint.append(last)`

Answer (score 0):

Using the other suggestion with `plt.yticks()` worked for me but caused uneven spacing between ticks. My original plot had ticks spaced an interval of 2.5 apart, so simply converting each location to an integer resulted in alternating tick distances of 2 and 3 (undesirable for my case). If others are running into the same issue, here is my workaround for integer ticks with even spacing:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
plt.plot(...

locs, labels = plt.yticks()  # retrieve original tick values
dloc = np.ceil(locs[1] - locs[0]).astype(int)  # get tick spacing
dloc_int = int(dloc)  # define new integer tick spacing

new_yticks = np.arange(locs.min(), locs.max(), dloc_int, dtype=int)
plt.yticks(new_yticks)
```

The issue is solved by predefining the tick spacing interval as an integer, then generating the new y-tick values in the array `new_yticks`, ensuring constant spacing between ticks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution using the

```
ticker.MaxNLocator(integer=True)
```

Somehow doesn't work for me. I guess it's because it's setting the ticks to be at integer values, but it doesn't force the ticks *labels* to also be integers.
I came up with this one-liner to force the labels to be integers and it works for me:

```
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticks().astype(int))
```