# Create numpy array with loop

Tags: python, numpy

I have some constant , for example, `0.5`. So i need to create a numpy array where first element will be equal constant (array[0]=0.5) and next one will be `1, 1.5, 2, 2.5...` (previous element plus constant). Lenght of this sequence must be `795`. 
Array what i need looks like:

```
array = ([0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5.....])
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Try `arange` or `linspace` for a start.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18265979/984885) - basically what you want is

```
import numpy
numpy.arange(0.5, 0.5 + 795 * 0.5, 0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`numpy.linspace`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html):

```
import numpy as np

res = np.linspace(0.5, 795*0.5, num=795)

array([   0.5,    1. ,    1.5,    2. ,    2.5,    3. ,    3.5,    4. ,
      ...
        396.5,  397. ,  397.5])
```