# Python multiprocessing, cannot iterate with pool.map

Tags: python, mapping, python-multiprocessing

I have a 32 core machine with 256gb ram and am new to parallel computing.
I have to run this line:

```
Flag=data.flag [:,:,x]
```

which is a very large matrix. "x" refers to the sub-matrix that I want to store to file. But "changes" 64 times and each iteration takes +- 8min, hence the need to parallelize it

I've looked at a few examples:
https://www.machinelearningplus.com/python/parallel-processing-python/
and
https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming

**Function for code:**

```
def multi_flagger(antenna_no):
    recv=data.corr_products[antenna_no][0]         # Gets the antenna name and polarization value
    flagger=data.flags[:, :, antenna_no]         # Flags the data based on the antenna value
    mat_flag = np.matrix(flagger)                # Morphs the 2d array into a matrix
    np.save('Flagged_data_'+str(recv)+'_.npy', mat_flag)  # Saves the data to a file

pool.map(multi_flagger, for i in range(2))
pool.close()
```

I get this error:

> ```
> File "<ipython-input-58-e1a6f9779b9a>", line 1
>    pool.map(multi_flagger, for i in range(2))
>                              ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax`
> ```

What I would like is 64 .npy files written to disk

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, but I believe your syntax error can be corrected by changing `for i in range(2)` to `list(range(2))`. Of course, that will only use two processes.

Comment: @JohnAnderson , thank you. I corrected it to list. I want to write the data (in the matrix) to file but the single loop takes too long and I wanted to parallelize it to do more at once

Answer (score 1):

The method [`Pool.map(func, iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) expects an iterable, which can be a `tuple` or a `list`. You cannot pass a `for` loop as what you have tried (`for i in range(2)`), but you can instead pass a [list of numbers from a range](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18265935/2745495):

```
pool.map(multi_flagger, list(range(2)))  # [0, 1]
```

I'm not sure about the rest of your code, but when using a `Pool`, you set the number of worker processes when you create the `Pool` instance (as explained in the [Using a pool of workers](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) example) and then call `map` to pass in the function to execute and the function inputs:

```
def multi_flagger(antenna_no):
    recv=data.corr_products[antenna_no][0]         
    flagger=data.flags[:, :, antenna_no]         
    mat_flag = np.matrix(flagger)                    
    np.save('Flagged_data_'+str(recv)+'_.npy', mat_flag)

with Pool(processes=3) as pool:               # set the number of worker processes
    pool.map(multi_flagger, list(range(2)))   # pass a list of antenna_no
    pool.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

so the question was to do with a specific package called "katdal" used in radio telescopes. I figured out the solution, it was because of the flagger line. The data needed to be read each time

`def multi_flagger(antenna_no):
    data = katdal.open('/'+prefix+'/'+fname+'/'+fname+'/'+fname+'_sdp_l0.full.rdb')

    recv=data.corr_products[antenna_no][0]   # Gets the antenna and polarization value
    flagger=data.flags[:, :, antenna_no]     # Flags the data based on the antenna value
    np.save('Flagged_data_'+str(recv)+'_.npy', np.matrix(flagger) )   # Morphs the 2d array into a matrix and Saves the data to a file`

But this leaves me with a new issue about the data file being read in all the time, essentially taking up time and space.