# Python 3 : How to create a list of lists based on the range function

Tags: python, list, python-3.6

I'm trying to create a list from a range, but when I stick it in another list I get a class and not the list of lists that I'm expecting - `[[0,1,2]]`

Code:

```
    initial_list = range(3)
    list_of_lists = [initial_list]
    for i in list_of_lists:
    print(i, type(i))
```

This outputs `range(0,3), <class 'range'>` However, I want `[[0,1,2]]` Does anyone know how to force range to expand?

Comment: simply replace `range(3)` with `list(range(3))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18265979/7431860) explains that you're pretty close! If you were in Python 2.x, this approach would have worked, since in 2.x, `range()` returns a list. In 3.x, however, `range()` returns an iterator.

Expand it with `list(range(3))` to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

You could append it to anotehr list.
Heres what i've done do to this:

```
initial_list = []
for i in range(3):
 initial_list.append(i)
list_of_lists = [initial_list]
```

Then in IDLE it Showed:

```
list_of_lists
[0, 1, 2]]
```