# replicate the seq function in R to python

Tags: python, r, numpy

I am trying replicate R's seq function in Python

For example in R:

```
sequence = seq(from = 1, to = 3, by = 1)
output = 1 2 3
```

And in Python I find the linspace commmand:

```
np.linspace(start=1, stop=3, num=1)
output = array([1.])
```

But it specifies the number of elements rather than the step size.

I was looking for something like R's output.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/18265935/680068 ?

Comment: I understand that these kinds of questions would be duplicates almost always, but I would appreciate the community to be understanding of the following situation: people like me, learning Python after R tend to ask questions exactly like the OP "What is the equivalent of X function in Python?". These are legit and normal questions given that one learns how to navigate the help documentation and "philosophy" of a new language. I am not yet aware of a place where such questions would be fully welcomed without feeling that we saturate StackOverflow with duplicated questions.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `num` is not equivalent to `by`.

> num: `int`, optional
>
> Number of samples to generate. Default is 50. Must
> be non-negative.

---

Try with

```
>>> np.linspace(start=1, stop=3, num=3)
array([1., 2., 3.])
```

Comment: so isnt there a replicate of by in python ?

Comment: np.arange(11, 17, 0.5).tolist()

Comment: @pylearner Well, `seq` equivalent is `np.linspace` but what I am saying is that `num` defines the number of samples you want to generate (in this case `3`) but in `seq`, `by` argument is actually the step.

Comment: oh i got it ... thanks @giorgos

Answer (score 0):

```py
[x for x in range(1, 4, 1)]
# [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: np.arange(11, 17, 0.5).tolist()