# how can I fix my histogram plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, histogram

I want to plot a very simple histogram diagram with python. Here is my code :

```
from numpy import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import*
from random import*
nums = []
N = 10
for i in range(N):
    a = randint(0,10)
    nums.append(a)

bars= [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
hist(nums)

show()
```

[This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDFSl.png)

How can I put the bars just in the integer place? Why does my diagram show the float numbers too?

Comment: Maybe the answers in this question already help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050393/force-the-y-axis-to-only-use-integers

Comment: hist by default uses 10 bins but in the min to max range which is not 0 to 10 since your numbers are random

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you make `bars` but then don't use it. If you set the `bins` option of `hist` to `bars`, it all works fine

```
bars= [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
hist(nums,bins=bars)
```

[image]

To set the `yticks` to only integer values, you can use a [`MultipleLocator`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator) from the [`matplotlib.ticker`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html) module:

```
from numpy import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import*
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
from random import*

nums = []
N = 10
for i in range(N):
    a = randint(0,10)
    nums.append(a)

bars= [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
hist(nums,bins=bars)

gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1))

show()
```

[image]

Comment: i think he wants to remove 0.5, 1.5 etc from the Y axis.

Comment: thanks,How can add density plot to this? something like this : http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/graphics/histograms-with-varying-bin-widths/ the red curve I mean