# matplotlib plot integers on X Axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have written a very simple piece of code using matplotlib where I want to plot integers on both x and y axis. (I am using Python3 on Raspberry pi)

I searched web and found this thread

[how to force matplotlib to display only whole numbers on the Y axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27496737/how-to-force-matplotlib-to-display-only-whole-numbers-on-the-y-axis)

Based on the suggestion, I wrote this code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for axis in [ax.xaxis, ax.yaxis]:
    axis.set_major_locator(ticker.MaxNLocator(integer=True))

plt.plot([2013, 2014, 2015, 2016], [20, 30, 40, 50])
plt.ylabel("Hot Dog Sales")
plt.xlabel("year")
plt.show()
```

But it still produces X axis like this

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following:

```
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain',axis='x',useOffset=False)
```

This forces scientific format off and removes the 2013 offset.