# How to get references to the current figure and axes object so that I can force bar plot y-axis to only display whole numbers

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

A similar question has been raised :

[how to force matplotlib to display only whole numbers on the Y axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27496737/how-to-force-matplotlib-to-display-only-whole-numbers-on-the-y-axis)

I am trying to do exactly the same for a bar plot. My problem is that the bar object does not unpack to fig, ax. Here is the code :

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
x = [0, 0.5, 1, 2, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5, 7.5, 8.5,9]
y = [1,2,2,3,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,0]
width = 0.5
plt.bar(x, y, width, color="pink")
plt.xlabel('score')
plt.ylabel('antall')
plt.show()
```

And the bar graph :

[image: A bar graph]

I would like to only display whole integers on y-axis and the opposite on the x-axis (i.e numbers 0 to 10 with 0.5 increment).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`fig = plt.gcf()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.gcf) and [`ax = plt.gca()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.gca) to get references to the current figures and axes objects.

However, using the `matplotlib` [object-oriented interface](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#coding-styles) always gives you have access to `fig` and `ax` and makes the code clearer which figure and axes you are controlling.

Also, you can use the [`matplotlib.ticker`](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html) module for more control over tick locations. In this case, a [`MultipleLocator`](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator) will do the trick to set the tick locations on multiples of `1` for the `yaxis` and `0.5` for the `xaxis`.

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

x = [0, 0.5, 1, 2, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5, 7.5, 8.5,9]
y = [1,2,2,3,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,0]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

width = 0.5
ax.bar(x, y, width, color="pink")
ax.set_xlabel('score')
ax.set_ylabel('antall')

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(0.5))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1))

plt.show()
```

[image]