# matplotlib - plt.bar wrong values in x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have created the following chart:

[image]

using the following code:

```
def plot_exercises_scores(exercise_list, scores, semester_id):
    print (exercise_list)
    plt.bar(exercise_list, scores, color='orange')
    plt.title("Exercise scores for " + semester_id, fontsize=20)
    plt.xlabel("exercise number", fontsize=16 )
    plt.ylabel("score", fontsize=16)
    plt.ylim(0, 100)
    plt.show()
```

Look at the x-axis - it shows the bar on values 0.75, 1.25, 1.75, 2.25 while they don't even exists in `exercise_list`.
`exercise_list = [1 2]`

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Look at the centers of each bar.

Comment: I don't want numbers I never had on the x-axis.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, pyplot always behaves like that, but by using a solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27496737/how-to-force-matplotlib-to-display-only-whole-numbers-on-the-y-axis) I made something like this:

[image]

If this is what you wanted, then here's full code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker


def plot_exercises_scores(exercise_list, scores, semester_id):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    # Be sure to only pick integer tick locations.
    for axis in [ax.xaxis, ax.yaxis]:
        axis.set_major_locator(ticker.MaxNLocator(integer=True))

    plt.bar(exercise_list, scores, color='orange')
    plt.title("Exercise scores for " + semester_id, fontsize=20)
    plt.xlabel("exercise number", fontsize=16)
    plt.ylabel("score", fontsize=16)
    plt.ylim(0, 100)
    plt.show()

    fig.tight_layout()


plot_exercises_scores([1, 2], [90, 85], "2018/2019a")
```