# How to customize bar graph (matplotlib)?

Tags: python

My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

f = plt.figure()
production_level = [54, 83, 21, 3] #list_of_prod
periods = [x+1 for x in range(len(production_level))] #list_of_order

plt.bar(periods, production_level, color='orange')

plt.title('Dynamic lot-size problem chart')
plt.ylabel('Units')
plt.xlabel('Periods')
plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
f.savefig("bar.png", bbox_inches='tight')
```

Output:
[image]

How can I have just whole numbers on x axis (1,2,3,4) without 0,5; 1,5; 2,5 etc.? How can add bars' value on them or above them?

Comment: An aside, `periods = range(1, len(production_level) + 1)` might be easier.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258212/python-matplotlib-restrict-to-integer-tick-locations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add text by using [plt.text()](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.text) and tweaking the coordinates (hint, hardcoding these values might not be the best idea).

Change ticks by using [plt.xticks()](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html) (see also [this question](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.text)).